# Can I replace post mount disc brakes calipers with flat mount calipers?

Tags: brakes, disc-brake

I have post mount TRP Spyre calipers, how can I upgrade to flat mount Ultegra calipers? are there adapters available? I've only seen adapters for flat to post.

Comment: I've closed this as a dupe of the other linked question because it had an accepted answer and was 6 months older.  Did you ever complete this job?  If so, feel free to add your own answer sharing how it went and what challenges you faced.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are no adapters on the market to use flat-mount calipers on a post mount fork, so your options are:

- Get a flat mount fork and Ultegra caliper you want. I actually did that, the additional price will depend on new/secondhand and no-name/open mold/brand name factors.
- Get any post mount Shimano hydraulic caliper, those are all compatible. There's no actual Ultegra post mount calipers, but prior to R8000, Shimano made a non-group, Ultegra-level ST-RS685/BR-RS785 shifters/calipers, so you might use a BR-RS785 or slightly older BR-R785 (actually an XT).

Comment: BR-RS785 has a straight hose connection while BR-R785 has the banjo.  So go with BR-RS785, or Deore BR-M6000.  Both are directly compatible with OP's other parts.

Comment: Yeah, but the banjo connector doesn't matter much unless there's a tight clearance. Just a matter of what hose to get.